# Return to referer (double back)

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, routes, referer

I often use referer when i want to redirect to the actually page :

```
$referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
return $this->redirect($referer);
```

But when I use this method I have to hit twice to the backward button (the button of any browser that will go to the last page used) ... So I want to know if there is the other method to redirect to the same page but without this double backward bug ... thanks for anyone that will help :)

I am talking about this button ---> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insted of use the referer, which could not be a secure method, you can:

1) Use some of the redirects methods provided by Symfony ([docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#redirecting)):

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
```

In case you don't really know what is your referer page, you can still pass the desired route as parameter to your controller, and use it in your `redirectToRoute` call.

2) Use JavaScript.

```
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
```

Probably, you need to execute some back-end operations before goBack method is executed, if is the case, you can use AJAX calls, and execute goBack method when servers responds.